# How do I get the object of the array put in the console, the arrow function with map is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nodes

How do I get the object in de console.log, because I tried this way;

```
var result = data.map(person => ({ value: person._id, text: person.name }));
console.log(result)
```

Only didn't work out. undefined.

Can someone help me?

[image]

If you can't see the image, console.log(data) put out this;

```
    Object

products: Array (183)
0 {_id: "5e96dea579936a2aa5882689", name
```

Comment: Same `data` would make people able to answer it. It is unclear how map would return `undefined`. More code would make this more clear.

Comment: ok so what is you trying to achieve with the code ? your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate this in JS Fiddle and it's working great: https://jsfiddle.net/o37hn18p/

```
var data = [{
    _id: "5e96dea579936a2aa5882689",
    name: "Strawberry"
},
{
    _id: "5e9643rfwe436a2aa5882689",
    name: "Flowers"
}
];

console.log("data:");
console.log(data);

var result = data.map(person => ({
  value: person._id,
  text: person.name
}));
console.log("\n\nresult:");
console.log(result);
```

If you can post more code 
we can investigate better